# save webpages for offline browsing

Tags: java, android, android-webview, offline-browsing

i am trying to create an android application that saves webpages to use it in **offline-browsing**, i was able to save the webpage but the problem was in the contents (images, javascripts,..etc), is there a way to do so **programmatically**, i use eclipse and test my work on an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, I am afraid you should parse html's yourself (I mean do that with a properly lib) and store all resources (css, js, images, videos etc.) too.
s. how it is done in a java crawler: [open source crawlers](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to search for all images, javascript files, css files, etc... and download them, saving them to the same relative path to the HMTL files - Assuming the html is coded with relative paths (`images/image.png`) and not absolute paths (`http://www.domain.com/image/image.png`).

You can pretty easily search the html string for `<img`, `<script`, `<link` etc.. and parse from there - or you can find a [3rd party html parser](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html+parser+php)